When a post with a suggested edit is locked, the suggested edit should be marked as "canceled", rather than "rejected"
Today, I suggested an edit to a post on English Language & Usage Stack Exchange. A few hours later, the suggested edit was rejected by the Community Bot due to the post being briefly locked:

Post was locked - suggested edit can not be processed

Note that the question was locked after the edit was submitted.
The question is not locked now, but closed due to off-topic. You can see the timeline if you need more details.
The suggested edit is now categorized as “rejected”, rather than “canceled” (or something that also means the same thing as “canceled”). Do you think that we should also categorize this kind of rejected edits as “canceled”, instead of “rejected”? (Like this issue: Edit conflicts should categorize as "cancelled" instead of "rejected")
When a suggested edit is cancelled due to things beyond the control of the edit's author, those edits should not be counted in the edit ban (i.e., should be marked as "canceled", not "rejected").

Although, a potentially more interesting question would be "why did the Community user lock and immediately unlock this question?"

Yes, but if I need to clarify the case when the Community Bot rejected my edits, I think I need to write a longer title…

No, you need to be more concise (something I, also, have issues with on a regular basis). Titles summarize; they don't need to tell the entire narrative. For example, the title could be: 'When a post with a suggested edit is locked, the suggested edit should be marked as "canceled", rather than "rejected".'

@Makyen this happened before, without any explanation.

@Makyen This happens when users vote to migrate the question but the migration is instantly rejected, due to the post being blocked on the destination site. Community locks the question, attempts to migrate, gets refused, and unlocks the question again.
